# Image Handler not Loading Image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, httphandler

I am using Image handler to resize image. But it is not loading image.

View :

```html
 <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?file=~/Images/Releases/koala.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
```

Image Handler code.[image]
Sorry I was not able to add the whole image handler code here so added as image.
What I am missing here. Please suggest.

Comment: Where's the handler code?

Comment: did you register your handler in the web.config?

Comment: Yes.Here is the code
 <add verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler,ImageHandler"/>

Comment: are you ignoring the route for the handler routes.IgnoreRoute("ImageHandler.ashx");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues.

1. QueryString value in the request URL should be just filename - `ImageHandler.ashx?file=koala.jpg`

   `<img src="ImageHandler.ashx?file=koala.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />`
2. QueryString name should be `file` instead of `photo_url`.

Please make sure the following code works before resizing it.

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{    
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
        string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Releases/" + fileName);

        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
             string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Invalid photo name.");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Comment: Please set a break point inside ImageHandler, and post the error message that you receive.

Comment: Error message displays 
 Could not create type 'PressRoom.ImageHandler'.
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="ImageHandler.ashx.cs" Class="PressRoom.ImageHandler" %>

Comment: It seems something is corrupted. Could you delete that handler file and create a new one?

Comment: I tried debugging my code.
 string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
 string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Releases/" + fileName);
fileName is null thats why its not rendering images. when I hard code image it is displaying.
How do I get the image image folder?

Comment: What is the value of `filePath` when you set a break point after that line? You will need to modify the path based on the file location in your project.

Comment: filepath value is \Images\Releases\
But the fileName is coming null so it is going into exception. 
In my view I am doing like this to display the images 

@foreach (var photos in Model.Photos)
                            {
                                 <div class="slide_one slide">
                                     <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?file=@photos.photo_url" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
                                </div>
                            }

Comment: `@photos.photo_url` is not a correct filename for query string. You need to set a break point at server-side and see how you can render filename.

Comment: Instead of passing direct image url to this 
 string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Releases/Koala.jpg" + fileName);
How do I get all the images which are stored in Images/Releases folder by passing id.
when I pass id from my view through url something like this
<img src="ImageHandler.ashx?id=1361" style="width:100px; height:100px;" /> 
I need to get all the images which are associate to that id

Comment: You need to store them in database. For example, `ID` and `FileName` pair in a table.

Comment: I have a table called Photos which stores photo_id and photo_url. How do i retrive images from DB using entity framework inside ashx file?

Comment: This thread becomes out of scope of the original question. Could you create a separate question regarding how to access data from database and what issue you are encountering?

Comment: I have created separate question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930432/get-images-from-database-in-entity-framework-by-passing-id-into-ashx

Comment: Does this answer solve the original issue regarding filename being passed to ImageHandler?

Comment: yes it solved the original issue regarding filename being passed to ImageHandler