# Get images from database in Entity Framework by passing id into ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, httphandler

In my homepage I Have a list of articles. When I click on any article it redirects to next page to view images of that article. in URL I am passing article id (`pr_id`) to next page. So to display resized images I am using handler. I need to display all the images which are associated to that `pr_id`.

How do I get all the images which are stored in DB by passing id in Entity Framework. I need to get all the images which are associate to that `pr_id`. I don't know where I am kind of stuck. In my DB `pr_id = 1362` has 3 images and in view I see 3 placeholders for that `pr_id` but it is broken or not displaying image.

When I debug ImageHandler.ashx

```
string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
```

`fileName` is showing null.

Do I need to get all the images by passing `pr_id` into the `ashx` file? If so how do I do that?

Image handler : ImageHandler.ASHX

```
namespace PressRoom
{   
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
            string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Releases/" + fileName);

            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
            string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            }
            else
            {
                 throw new HttpException(404, "Invalid photo name.");
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        byte[] getResizedImage(String path, int width, int height)
        {
            Bitmap imgIn = new Bitmap(path);

            double y = imgIn.Height;
            double x = imgIn.Width;

            double factor = 1;

            if (width > 0)
            {
                factor = width / x;
            }
            else if (height > 0)
            {
                factor = height / y;
            }

            System.IO.MemoryStream outStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            Bitmap imgOut = new Bitmap((int)(x * factor), (int)(y * factor));

            // Set DPI of image (xDpi, yDpi)
            imgOut.SetResolution(72, 72);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut);
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.DrawImage(imgIn, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(factor * x), (int)(factor * y)),
                     new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)x, (int)y), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            imgOut.Save(outStream, getImageFormat(path));

            return outStream.ToArray();
        }

        string getContentType(String path)
        {
            switch (Path.GetExtension(path))
            {
                case ".bmp": return "Image/bmp";
                case ".gif": return "Image/gif";
                case ".jpg": return "Image/jpeg";
                case ".png": return "Image/png";
                default: break;
            }

            return "";
        }

        ImageFormat getImageFormat(String path)
        {
            switch (Path.GetExtension(path))
            {
                case ".bmp": return ImageFormat.Bmp;
                case ".gif": return ImageFormat.Gif;
                case ".jpg": return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                case ".png": return ImageFormat.Png;
                default: break;
            }

            return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        }
    } 
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (var photos in Model.Photos)
{
    <div class="slide_one slide">
        <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?file=@photos.photo_url" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
    </div>
}
```

[My database table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Xb4.png)

Comment: Three questions. Is 'Koala.jpg' a directory? Are you trying to get a collection of images? Are you trying to put them all into that img tag?

Comment: No, Koala.jpg is image. My image directory is ~\Images\Releases. I am trying to get collection of images by passing pr_id , Each pr_id had multiple images. and trying to put them in img tag.

Comment: You need to write a code to query a `photo` from database table based on the given `photo_id`. Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: I think you need to retrieve the paths and if it's in it load the collection of images directly from the server.

Comment: When I debug ImageHandler.ashx  
string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"]; 
fileName is showing null
Do i need to get all the images by passing pr_id into ashx file? if so how do I do that?

Comment: I think your collection of images has to be in the context when you call the handler. You're going to need a loop to iterate over the collection. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Getting 'System.ArgumentException'  at Bitmap imgIn = new Bitmap(path);